# How to set common format for toLocaleString?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use JS function `toLocaleString` for date formatting. How can I set one common format for all clients like:

```
2015-10-29 20:00:00
```

That I do parsong at PHP by `-`

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: > How can I set one common format for all clients like < client **don't** depend of server

Comment: I tried function `toLocaleString` for string `Wed Oct 28 2015 00:00:42 GMT+0400 (Грузинское время (зима))`

Comment: On client I get date in full format. I need to convert it to `datetime` format for MySQL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you would have to manually parse it into that format, which actually isn't too bad. What Date.toLocaleString() returns is a format of:

```
MM/DD/YYYY, HH:MM:SS
```

Here's my code snippet to help you out:

```
// Parse our locale string to [date, time]
var date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US',{hour12:false}).split(" ");

// Now we can access our time at date[1], and monthdayyear @ date[0]
var time = date[1];
var mdy = date[0];

// We then parse  the mdy into parts
mdy = mdy.split('/');
var month = parseInt(mdy[0]);
var day = parseInt(mdy[1]);
var year = parseInt(mdy[2]);

// Putting it all together
var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + time;
```

Comment: So does your code return format  `MM/DD/YYYY, HH:MM:SS` always? For each clients?

Comment: Yes, it always returns this format. You will need to append a 0 to the front of some months and some days if your format is strict, since parseInt changes a month like 03 to 3. That can be easily fixed by a check such as : if (day < 10) { day = '0' + day; }

Comment: no it is wrong try `console.log( (new Date()).toLocaleString( "ko-KR" ) );
console.log( (new Date()).toLocaleString( "en-GB" ) );
console.log( (new Date()).toLocaleString( "ar-EG" ) );` this is according locale setting for the browser/computer

Comment: This is why I set the locale string to 'en-US'. The locale really doesn't matter if the date isn't being displayed to the user. I don't understand why you are inserting different locales when all of them can convert to a single format to be parsed.

Comment: Why parsing a Date.toLocaleString result if we can directly access the Date object ??

Comment: It was closer to what OP already had as a solution, and does not involve any complex JS knowledge such as prototypes that he might not understand.

Comment: But not supported by all browsers ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Ah fair point! Direct access on the Date object is also simpler.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the format as described (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) by adding the locale parameter, like this:

```
toLocaleString("sv-SE")
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring_date_all

Answer (score 2):

you can use moment.js library which has many features to work with date & time you can easily format a date with that.

here is an example
`moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // will print in 2015-10-29 20:00:00 format`

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

before doing what i provide please read [this](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) and [this](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('dbg');
var log = function(val){el.innerHTML+='<div><pre>'+val+'</pre></div>'};
var pad = function(val){ return ('00' + val).slice(-2)};

Date.prototype.myFormattedString = function(){
  return this.getFullYear()     + '-' + 
        pad( (this.getMonth() + 1) )   + '-' + 
        pad( this.getDate() )          + ' ' + 
        pad( this.getHours() )         + ':' + 
        pad( this.getMinutes() )       + ':' +
        pad( this.getSeconds() )
    ;
}

var curDate = new Date();

log( curDate )
log( curDate.toLocaleString() )
log( curDate.myFormattedString() )
```

```html
<div id='dbg'></div>
```