# How can I format time

Tags: javascript

I get this time stamp from the database **:**

```
2022-09-06T07:11:59.002Z
```

How can I format it to something like this ?

```
2022-09-06 07:11:59
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? There are a lot of questions like that around.

Comment: This is a great start for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057479/8816585 `options` on `toLocaleString` is quite customizable, but if you want something more friendly you can also use a library. Maybe the Temporal API can be of some use too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of `RegEx` by using [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method along with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Live Demo **:**

```js
const str = '2022-09-06T07:11:59.002Z';

const res = str.replace(str.match(/(\.).*/g)[0], '').replace('T', ' ');

console.log(res);
```

*Updating the answer as per the comment by author (In Vue.js format) :*

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: {
        time: '2022-09-06T07:11:59.002Z'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ product.time.replace(product.time.match(/(\.).*/g)[0], '').replace('T', ' ') }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: let's say the time is <p>{{product.time}} </p> in my html and its return that string how can I change it in vue

Comment: @xander I updated answer as per your requirement. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

This not related to VueJS, it's a pure JavaScript question:

Ill suggest to transform the string date to a `Date` Object, and then you can manipulate it easily:

```js
    const date = new Date('2022-09-06T07:11:59.002Z');

    console.log(date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '));
   
    console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }));
```

More information about [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)